# What is wrong with jQuery ajax function for sending RegisterationId to our server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, push-notification

I get started working with pushNotification service for my android app.

I receive a registration Id from GCM server successfully and attempt to send this Id to our server by means of a jQuery ajax function. Moreover, I intend to send this Id after login in my application.

My problem is that my ajax function doesn't go into success callback function.

I don't know what causes this problem. Am I doing something wrong in my GCM mechanism or the problem is related to my ajax function?

Here is my code.

```
function logIn(email, userPassword) {
var _email = email;
var _userPassword = userPassword;
var _url = getUrl('login');
var _xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><login><email>' + _email + '</email><password>' + _userPassword + '</password></login>';

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data : _xmlString,
    contentType: "application/xml",
    url : _url,
    headers : {
        "Brand" : "HUS",
        "RequestId" : createUUID()
    },
    success : function(dataObject, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        pushNotification();

    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connected.\n Please verify network is connected.');
        }

}
});
}

function pushNotification() {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    var devicePlatform = device.platform;
    if (devicePlatform == 'android' || devicePlatform == 'Android') {
        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
            "senderID" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "ecb" : "onNotificationGCM"
        });
    }
};

// handle GCM notifications for Android
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    switch (e.event) {
    case 'registered':
        if (e.regid.length > 0) {
        //TODO call server
          sendRegisterationId(e.regid); 
        }
        break;
    case 'message':
        alert('message = ' + e.message + ' msgcnt = ' + e.msgcnt);
        break;
    case 'error':
        alert('GCM error = ' + e.msg);
        break;
    default:
        alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
        break;
    }
}


function sendRegisterationId(regId){
var _regId = regId;
var _url = getUrl('addPushId');
alert('get regId from GCM: \n' + _regId + ' \n\n url: ' + _url);

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : _url,
    data : _regId,
    timeout : 30000,
    headers : {
        "Session-Token" : _sessionToken,
        "Brand" : "HUS",
        "RequestId" : createUUID()
    },
    success : function() {
        alert("hello");
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //TODO Error handling
        alert("failed to send regId");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I assume that onNotificationGCM being called and going through the 'registered' path then and calling sendRegistrationId() ?

Comment: Silly me, Sorry. You mean that you can't attach a debugger?

Comment: @jwwishart: actually I fixed the problem. I did a mistake in my ajax request in sendRegisterationId(). There ín the header I just reffer to _sessionToken variable,but forgot to set the value.  this is correct: "Session-Token" : getSessionToken(). Moreover, my data format was wrong. In our backed, we needed to receive platform name as well. In my code I just sent pushId.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest starting with looking at your network trace in your browser and see if 1. the request is actually being sent and 2. what the error is (I'm assuming an error thus success not being triggered)

Comment: Thanks for your response! actually I have already an error callback in my ajax function. I added an alert there, but it seems sendRegisterationId() never runs the my ajax function.

Comment: The alert only shows for status zero which I think means that the request was no allowed to be performed (i.e. cross site scripting) what about other status' - do you know whether the request is being sent and whether it fails? i.e. network tab or just write out the status and textStatus given in error() to the console and see what it shows...

Comment: I've got to remember to scroll. I though the page I could see was all the code :o)

Comment: @ jwwishart I handle these errors jqXHR.status === 0, jqXHR.status === 401. I don't have any Problem with login. My problem is executing ajax function in sendRegisterationId(regId) function.

Comment: I always run the appliction in nexus 7. not in browser.